# How to stabilize this system?

Tags: control-system, stability, laplace-transform

I'm trying to understand system stability basics. Let us say I have a system
$$
    G(s) = \frac{500}{s^2 - 500}
$$

Since it has two poles in the right half s-plane, it is unstable.

How can I stabilize it? I have read that a simple pole-zero cancellation would mostly be unreliable.

Comment: What happens if you add unity gain negative feedback? After you analyze that, try negative feedback with a gain of 2 in the feedback path.

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-loop_transfer_function) ... This is  the expression for the closed-loop response. You want the poles of *that* expression to be stable. You can work it out algebraically. The [root locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_locus#Definition) method helps develop intuition for cases such as yours. (note the wiki explanation for this is pretty confusing, there are some good youtube vids that might be better)

Comment: Note: you will add some other function in front of "your" G(s), let's call it F(s). This is the "compensator". It might simply be a fixed gain, if so call that K.  When the notation of the wiki page says G(s) , it will really be F(s)G(s), or KG(s) if it is just a fixed gain.  H(s) can simply be 1 for now, for simplicity. Most of the time, the "design task" is to figure out what F(s) should be to make the whole loop perform as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Routh–Hurwitz matrix to stabilize the system.

A Routh–Hurwitz matrix is a method for checking wheather or not a system is stable. It can also be used to stabilize the system by giving you a new denominator function for G(s).

According to this method, a system will be stable if the first column of the Routh–Hurwitz matrix contains only positive values.

You can stabilize the system by introducing a gain *k* and re-calculate the Routh–Hurwitz matrix to determine this *k* value that makes the system stable. In other words you can stabilize the system by inteoducing feed-back into it to conpensate for the unstable components of G(s).

Check these additional resources if you're still unsure about how to do this:

> http://control.asu.edu/Classes/MAE318/318Lecture10.pdf

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBCZBOB3LCA